# What is wrong with my copy command?

Tags: osx, symlink, cp, etc

I did the following to my mac with the intention to copy the `/etc` in  `/tmp` to try something:

```
$cd /tmp    
$cp -a /etc .  
$cd etc  
-bash: cd: etc: No such file or directory  
$ls -all etc  
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 jim jim 11 Dec 18 17:44 etc -> private/etc
```

What happened? I don't understand. What is this `etc -> private/etc` and why `etc` is not a directory in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mac it seems that /etc is only a symbolic link pointing to /private/etc. You only copied the link not a directory.

You can achieve what you are trying by copying the directory where the link is pointing or specifying `-H` option for `cp`.

Comment: Is it safe to do `rm -rf etc` inside `/tmp`?

Comment: Yes, it should  be ok. If it is only a link, then you don't even need -r option.